# dot2tex conversion failing

Tags: conversion, dot2tex

I'm having some trouble using the dot2texi package. I'm using the Sublime Text 2 editor to compile my LaTeX files, and I have LaTeXTools installed. I'm running this on Mac OSX, Mountain Lion.

The problem is simply that the dot conversion to tex is failing. I have all necessary packages installed, and if I manually run dot2tex from command line, it produces the figure all well and fine. So I'm guessing this is some problem from the Sublime end? I did a debug log output, and here's the relevant snippet from the log:

```
\openout3 = `test_latex-dot2tex-fig1.dot'.

Opening dot2tex stream test_latex-dot2tex-fig1.dot
runsystem(dot2tex --figonly -ftikz     --debug --prog=neato -tmath  -o test_lat
ex-dot2tex-fig1.tex  test_latex-dot2tex-fig1.dot)...executed.

Package dot2texi Warning: Conversion of test_latex-dot2tex-fig1.dot failed..

Package dot2texi Warning: Please convert test_latex-dot2tex-fig1.dot manually.
```

The LaTeX code I'm trying to compile is the simple example from the tutorial:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[debug]{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,mathmode]
digraph G {
node [shape="circle"];
a_1 -> a_2 -> a_3 -> a_4 -> a_1;
}
\end{dot2tex}
\end{document}
```

Earlier, I had enabled -shell-escape in my LaTeXTools build file, and debugged some _nocomma error out from running dot2tex (Python related). After all those issues were resolved, I could compile dot files from command line using dot2tex without any issues. I can't figure out why it fails in Sublime Text 2 and would like to resolve this for ease-of-use purposes. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

P.S. I have an inkling it might be something to do with the command being run from the wrong directory, so it can't find the dot file... I have no idea how to confirm that or fix it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The error look as if `--shell-escape` is not enabled, in particular, if you do the conversion by hand. Can you double check that this works?

Comment: Hi and thanks! Well I initially had problems with enabling shell-escape, and following whatever little I could find through google, it wasn't working until all of a sudden, the warning "Shell-escape is not enabled" disappeared. I'm using the following change in the LaTeX.sublime-build file: 

"cmd": ["latexmk", "-cd",
"-e", "\$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
//"-silent",
"-shell-escape",
"-f", "-pdf"],

Is there any other way to double check? As I mentioned, if I do it manually on command line, incl. the command inside runsystem(...) above, everything works.

Comment: Looks good to me. I thought about double checking with other packages that require `-shell-escape`, like the `python` package. But of course this can also be a path problem in the environment, maybe a Sublime expert has to have a look.

Comment: Finally found a solution, which I've posted below. You were right about it being a problem with the path in the environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah I finally found the answer, thanks to the Readme over at [master builder](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/tree/mbuilder). The problem description and solution can be found under the Troubleshooting > Path Issues section. For convenience, I'll copy-paste the relevant portion here:

> On Mac OS X, just having your `$PATH` set up correctly in a shell
>   (i.e., in Terminal) does not guarantee that things will work when you
>   invoke commands from ST. If something seems to work when you invoke
>   `pdflatex` or `latexmk` from the Terminal, but building from within ST
>   fails, you most likely have a path configuration issue. One way to
>   test this is to launch ST from the Terminal, typing
>
> `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`
>
> (and then Return; this is for ST2 of course) at the prompt. If things
>   do work when you run ST this way, but they fail if you launch ST from
>   the Dock or the Finder, then there is a path problem. From the
>   Terminal, type
>
> `echo $PATH`
>
> and take note of what you get. Then, run ST from the Dock or Finder,
>   open the console (with Ctrl+ `) and type
>
> `import os; os.environ['PATH']`
>
> and again take note of what you see in the output panel (right above
>   the line where you typed the above command). Finally, look at the
>   `path` keyword in the `osx` section of the `LaTeX.sublime-build` file
>   in the LaTeXTools package directory. For things to work, every
>   directory that you see listed from the Terminal must be either in the
>   list displayed when you type the `import os...` command in the ST
>   console, or else it must be explicitly specified in
>   `LaTeX.sublime-build`. If this is not the case, add the relevant paths
>   in `LaTeX.sublime-build` and please let me know, so I can decide
>   whether to add the path specification to the default build file.
>   Thanks!

This worked like a charm for me, all I had to do was replace whatever was after the `"path":` declaration with the shell output from `echo $PATH`. Hope that helps anyone having this problem.